# Trying to use and ID inside a route function laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, routes

Hi i'm trying to use the ID of the route to create a list of players for that tournament. However i can't seem te get the ID to be availble inside my excel creator.

[image]

```
Route::get('toernooien/{id}/spelers/excelexport', function($id){
        Excel::create('Export spelers toernooi '. $id, function($excel) {
            $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) {
                $ingeschrevenspelers = \App\UserToernooi::with('users')->where('toernooiid', '=', $id)->get()->all();
                foreach($ingeschrevenspelers as $ingeschrevenspeler){
                    $sheet->row($ingeschrevenspeler->users->id, array(
                        'Voornaam:' . $ingeschrevenspeler->users->voornaam,
                        'Tussenvoegsel:' . $ingeschrevenspeler->users->tussenvoegsel,
                        'Achternaam:' . $ingeschrevenspeler->users->achternaam,
                        'Woonplaats:' . $ingeschrevenspeler->users->woonplaats,
                        'Telefoonnummer:' . $ingeschrevenspeler->users->telefoonnummer,
                        'e-mail:' . $ingeschrevenspeler->users->email,
                    ));
                }
            });

        })->download('xls');
    });
```

I would like to use the highlighted ID in the get route function 
inside my $ingeschrevenspelers var to get the list of users subscribed to that tournament. I tried adding the $id var next to $excel and $sheet but nothing seems to be working.

I'm using http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export
as excel exporter.

Thanks in advance

Jordy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
Excel::create('Export spelers toernooi '. $id, function($excel) {
```

you need to change it to:

```
Excel::create('Export spelers toernooi '. $id, function($excel) use ($id) {
```

As you need to pass the variables that will be used inside [Anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) using '`use`' keyword

Answer (score 1):

it won't be available because you are using it inside an anonymous function.

change the your code from

`Excel::create('Export spelers toernooi '. $id, function($excel) {`

to

`Excel::create('Export spelers toernooi '. $id, function($excel) use ($id) {`